# Selecting active record objects out of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I am doing a few active record queries and then appending them into an array that was created before. What I am wanting to do is to do select out of this array ones that where created in the last month. Not sure how you do it as you cant do a where anymore as its not an active record array anymore.

e.g. (simple example bellow **I cant combine the queries in my actual code)

```
results = []
results += Post.where(:category_id => 1)
results += Post.where(:user_id => 1)
results += Post.where(:user_id => 4)
```

now i want to get out of the results array ones that were created in the last month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use ruby `Enumerable#select`:

```
 results.select { |post| post.created_at >= 1.month.ago }
```

Comment: In Rails you can write `1.month.ago`

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach than the other answers

```
results = []

posts = Post.where('created_at >= ?', Time.now - 1.month)
results << posts.where(category_id: 1)
results << posts.where(user_id: 1)
results << posts.where(user_id: 4)
```

If you have `user_id` in an array you can do this too

```
user_ids = [1,4]
results << posts.where(user_id: user_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting the objects into the array, in which case you can still use properties such as `created_at` on those objects. `created_at >= 1.month.ago` should work as a parameter in your query. Depending on how you're chaining:

`Post.where("created_at >= ?", 1.month.ago)` or `results_array.select { |post| post.created_at >= 1.month.ago }`